# Angular2 check/detect ng-content select exist from parent node *ngIf statement

Tags: angular, components, detection, sections, angular2-ngcontent

My question is about checking that `<some_selector>` connected with `<ng-content select='some_selector'>` was given or not in parent component. May be I give example for clarify:

We have parent component template (editor.html):

Here is my editor

```
<modal>
    Some contents
    <mfoot><button calss='btn' (click)="close()">Close</button></mfoot>
</modal>
```

And in modal component template (modal.html) we want to use such *ngIf statement:

```
<div class="modal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" *ngIf='hasNgContent("mfoot")' >
        <ng-content select="mfoot"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

We want to not show div.modal-footer if `<mfoot>` tag was nod used in editor template inside `<modal>` tag. So how to implement `hasNgContent()` method? or may be in angular2 there is more direct `*ngIf` statement that allow detect that `<mfoot>` tag was used in parent component  tag or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with @ContentChildren and see the length of the collection. Something like:

```
@ContentChildren(mfootComponent) children: QueryList<mfootComponent>;
```

this will populate with all mfootComponents, so you can check whether you have any. I hope it helps.

Comment: what is mfootComponent ? I have only two components 'modal' and 'editor'. Tag `<mfoot>` is not component ! It is used only for `ng-content select`

Comment: Ok, so your Idea is to not make free tags likie <mfoot> but rather make <mfoot> as componen - it some solution "out of the box" but I will accept it. (but I don't try it becouse in mean time a found alternative solution)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is a little dirty and use jQuery, but I don't see any other way in question frame (so without make tag `<mfoot>` as separate component):

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ... } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.html',
})
export class Modal implements AfterViewInit {

    modalEl = null;

    constructor(private _rootNode: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.modalEl = $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find('div.modal');
    }

    hasNgContent(selector:string) {
        return $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find(selector).length;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe instead of giving minuses, give constructive solution (the hasNgContent function body) without using `<mfoot>` as component.